# Insert data to MySQL for selected days in next few weeks

Tags: php, mysql

I have one specific task for one website and I simply can not create logic for that in my head. I have select boxes where user have to select when he wants to receive deliveries of something. So first select box is for weeks, second for frequency and last he can check days based on frequency.

So client wants to receive shipments in next 3 weeks 3 times a week on days Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

How I should make PHP function to insert that into some table where I will store all deliveries?

This is picture of form:

[image]

Now I need to select for example 2 weeks, 3 times and to check 3 days for that.

At the end I need to get 6 rows in mysql table.

```
 ID  DAY    DATE    TITLE

 1. monday - 07.11 - delivery one
 2. wednesday - 09.11 - delivery two
 3. friday - 11.11 - delivery three
 4. monday - 14.11 - delivery four
 5. wednesday - 16.11 - delivery five
 6. friday - 18.11 - delivery six
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample data and code, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: well I am stuck here, I tried a lot of stuff with for and foreach but no success. I just can say that I catch those days in one field in table like monday,wednesday,friday

Answer (score 0):

You can make a sql request for all checked days (with pdo object):

```
$j = 1;
for ($i=0; $i < $_POST["duration"]; $i++) { 
    if($_POST["monday"]) //isChecked
    {
        $db->execute("insert into yourTable (day, date, title) values('monday', '"./* the date of the day */."', 'delivery ".$j."')"); //with auto increment for id
        $j++;
    }
    if($_POST["tuesday"]) //isChecked
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and this will insert query if that day is checked and if not I can skip it. I will try that.

Comment: The `$_POST["monday"]` could be done with an inner loop, otherwise this will represent a lot of repeated code. Moreover, whilst this code looks safe because all injected values are trusted, it will be worth using parameter binding, especially if the date is to come from the user - otherwise a SQL injection vulnerability will result.

Comment: sure, be more efficient than this repetitive code but the global idee is here.

Comment: sql injection with pdo ?
if u use the prepare function u cant be injected bro ...